# symfony 3 many to many Bidirectional Extra Lazy Associations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony

i have two entities Advert 1 City

One Advert belong to Many cities

One city has many Adverts

i need a solution to associate this two entities and my objectif is:

Get $cities from an $advert object

Get $adverts from an $city

$advert->getCities()

$City->getAdverts()

```html
<?php

namespace Ligo\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;

/**
 * Advert
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ligo\PlatformBundle\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="City")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="adverts_cities",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $Cities;
```

```html
<?php

namespace Ligo\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * City
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="city")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ligo\PlatformBundle\Repository\CityRepository")
 */
class City
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Advert", mappedBy="Cities")
    **/
    private $Adverts;
```

Comment: * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="Adverts") inside class advert. then it should work provided you have the setters and getters... the jointable part should not be necessary. It should already know to join and give you what you want. Adding a manual join table is if you want something custom. Then run 
app/console generate:doctrine:entities LigoPlatformBundle:City
app/console generate:doctrine:entities LigoPlatformBundle:Advert
And it will update your setters and getters